# How to not Mock an object when using Mockito and CDI?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have an object reads configuration properties like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
    public class Configuration {

    @Inject
    @Config(value = "endpoint.base", defaultValue = "http://localhost:52885/consumers")
private String base;

    public String getBase() { return base; } 

}
```

this object is injected to a service object like this:

```
public class LoyaltyService {

    final Sender sender;

    final Configuration config;

    @Inject
    public LoyaltyService(Sender sender, Configuration config) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

I am now testing this service object with Mockito. I want to mock the Sender object, but I don't want to mock the configuration, or at least I just want to use the default value defined inside the object.

How can I do that in a Test object?

For example, I tried the following:

```
public class LoyaltyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private Sender sender;

    @Inject
    private Configuration config;

    private LoyaltyService target;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when (sender.post(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("Post Success");
        target  =new LoyaltyService(sender, config);
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem CDI will register the Config object at all. How does this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't seem CDI will register the Config object at all.

The CDI beans are not initialised when running the test, only the mocked objects are.

[`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html#initMocks(java.lang.Object)) only initializes

> objects annotated with Mockito annotations for given testClass: @Mock, @Spy, @Captor, @InjectMocks.

You need to use a CDI test framework like [cdi-unit](https://github.com/BrynCooke/cdi-unit) or [Pax Exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM4) in your test class to create the non-mocked beans for you.

Comment: thanks, those documents are everywhere, didn't realize it, but after trying again and again, I kinda feel like that is the case. What you said just confirms it.